# Problem with std::chrono::duration convert

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How I convert `std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>` in a `std::chrono::nanoseconds` in this example:

```
#include <chrono>

void main(void)
{
    auto ld = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>(0.001);
    //std::chrono::nanoseconds ns = convertToNanoSec(ld); //How to do this?
}
```

Convert `std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>` in a `std::chrono::nanoseconds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that there are two answers here:

1. The literal answer to your question.
2. The answer to the question you intended.

The literal answer to your question is that you can use any of<sup>1</sup>

- `std::chrono::duration_cast`
- `std::chrono::floor`
- `std::chrono::ceil`
- `std::chrono::round`

to convert any duration to any other duration.  When converting from floating-point-based durations to integral-based durations I like to use `round` which rounds to nearest.  This tends to minimize unexpected results due to the fact that the floating-point representation may not be able to exactly represent the value you're expecting.

Example:

```
auto ld = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>(0.001);
std::chrono::nanoseconds ns = std::chrono::round<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(ld);
```

Use of local using directives or using declarations, combined with provided type aliases can make this more readable:

```
auto ld = duration<long double, nano>(0.001);
auto ns = round<nanoseconds>(ld);
```

In both of these examples the results is 0 nanoseconds, which I'm guessing is not the answer you intended.  The reason for this is that `ld` is holding <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1000</sub> of a nanosecond, not <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1000</sub> of a second.

Thus my second answer:

I'm guessing you have 0.001 seconds that you want to express as an integral number of nanoseconds (1,000,000).  If that is the case then the first thing to do is convert the 0.001 long double to a long-double-based duration that represents seconds, not nanoseconds:

```
auto ld = std::chrono::duration<long double>(0.001);
```

And then proceed as before:

```
auto ns = round<nanoseconds>(ld);
```

Now `ns` holds a million nanoseconds.

---

<sup>1</sup> `floor`, `ceil` and `round` were introduced in C++17.  Prior to that only `duration_cast` comes in the std toolbox, but you can find the rest in free, open source code.